# How to share a part of the site in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

we have events listing website and events from different organizers are grouped (by URL), like -

```
www.site.com/organizer/event1
www.site.com/organizer/event2
www.site.com/organizer/event3
```

etc. How to give an organizer an access only to his/her part of the site's Google Analytics?

Easy way -

1. An organizer registers in Google Analytics
2. An organizer creates a counter in Google Analytics
3. An organizer sets this counter in his/her profile on our website.
4. We add this counter to our Google Analytics code on www.site.com/organizer/* pages
5. He/she clicks on some link in the profile and sees the GA stat only for own events.

The way I want it:

1. He/she clicks on some link in the profile and sees the GA stat only for own events.

Is this possible with some API to separate statistics for www.site.com/organizer/* and share a private link to it with organizer?

Comment: when you say counter, do you mean tracking code?

Comment: I mean account ID, like UA-XXXXX-1. GA allows to track more than one account on one page, so for example if our main account is UA-XXXXX-1 and user's is UA-XXXXX-2, on www.site.com/organizer/* pages we can track both UA-XXXXX-1 and UA-XXXXX-2.

Comment: you could create separate profiles(views) add filters so that only the data you want is displayed then give the user access to that profile(view)

Comment: Can you point to GA API docs pages for these functions? I can't try your suggestions as I can't see which functions are used for that. BTW I've found the similar approach in a competitor, Yandex.Metrika, also free service but Russian only. Their API is more straightforward, I can create a filter-based counter (as they call it) with public access rights just in two lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments in another answer (which is basically just a copy of the comment I left on your question).   I have changed my recommendation left in comment, think you should use the Google Analytics API for this.

Since you want to give others access to your own data I suggest you use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).  You will need to do this in a server sided programing language, say PHP or C#.

Every night run a job that will extract the data you want though the [Core reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide).  Store it in the database then create a page that will then display only the data you want to the different people.  You will only need to run your job once per day as the data for previous days will never change.  Wait at least 24 hours to get the data as data hasn't completed processing for 24 hours.

I am not sure what language plan on using but these tutorials should get you started: [Google Service Account with PHP](http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/) or [Google Analytics API Authentication with C#](http://www.daimto.com/googleanalytics-authentication-csharp/)

Comment: That looks interesting, but after storing the data on my server how to display them? GA itself has an extremely advanced interface I can't reproduce. We use Python BTW.

Comment: This is the way to go. Properties are not for such a task. Multiple Views would become unmanageable in the long run.

Comment: I cant help with python but here is someone who maybe can http://www.marinamele.com/use-google-analytics-api-with-python she might be able to help you get a service account working as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would create different profile views with filters to include only the subset of data for the subpages.

This way, you can add a specific user access rights to that specific profile only, so they can only view that profile when they log in.

Create an include only filter which filters on Request URI: /organizer/event1, /organizer/event2, /organizer/event3 etc.

Comment: Is it possible to create filters and assign user rights to them with API?

Comment: I belive you can do this through the management API, no? https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/

Comment: Still don't get it. As a result I want user to click on some URL and see the stats of his events. I probably can build this link using filters (like filters=ga:pagePath=~/organizer/event1). Can I ?

Comment: Filters aren't owned by a user they are assigned to the profile or view so no you cant create filters and assign user rights to them via the API

Comment: Well, the word filter might be a bit ambiguous here, as it means both filtering your data but also applying a filter to your profiles to filter it during processing. If you apply a view filter to your profile, then you could do as I suggested.

And it is easy to circumvent filters if you link them through a property which hold all data and only filters on the URI/pagePath.